# Slow Row-wise Comparison with For-loops in NumPy - How to improve?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I'm using `python` and `numpy` to compare two arrays or equal shape with coordinates (x,y,z) in order to match them, which look like that:

```
coordsCFS
array([[ 0.02      ,  0.02      ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.03      ,  0.02      ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.02      ,  0.025     ,  0.        ],
        ..., 
       [ 0.02958333,  0.029375  ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.02958333,  0.0290625 ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.02958333,  0.0296875 ,  0.        ]])
```

and

```
coordsRMED
array([[ 0.02      ,  0.02      ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.02083333,  0.02      ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.02083333,  0.020625  ,  0.        ],
       ..., 
       [ 0.03      ,  0.0296875 ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.02958333,  0.03      ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.02958333,  0.0296875 ,  0.        ]])
```

The data are read from two hdf5 files with h5py.
For the comparison I use [allclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html), which tests for "almost equality". The coordinates do not match within python's regular floating point precision. This is the reason I used the for loops, otherwise it would have worked with `numpy.where`. I usually try to avoid for loops, but in this context I couldn't figure out how. So I came up with this surprisingly slow snippet:

```
mapList = []
for cfsXYZ in coordsCFS:
    # print cfsXYZ
    indexMatch = 0
    match = []
    for asterXYZ in coordRMED:
        if numpy.allclose(asterXYZ,cfsXYZ):
            match.append(indexMatch)
            # print "Found match at index " + str(indexMatch)
            # print asterXYZ
        indexMatch += 1

    # check: must only find one match. 
    if len(match) != 1:
        print "ERROR matching"
        print match
        print cfsXYZ
        return 1

    # save to list
    mapList.append(match[0])

if len(mapList) != coordsRMED.shape[0]:
    print "ERROR: matching consistency check"
    print mapList
    return 1
```

This is very slow for my test sample size (800 rows). I plan to compare much larger sets. I could remove the consistency check and use `break` in the inner for loop for some speed benefit. Is there still a better way?

Comment: Can you better explain what the problem with the precision is?

Comment: If I use e.g. the last line in `coordsCFS` and test for equality: `((np.sum(coordsRMED == coordsCFS[-1],axis=1))==3).any()` I always get `False`. I think this is because the coordinates do not match good enough for numpy/python's `==`. The arrays come from very different programs...

Comment: What about `coordsRMED[-1] == coordsCFS[-1]`?

Comment: array([False, False, True], dtype=bool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get rid of the inner loop with something like this:

```
for cfsXYZ in coordsCFS:
    match = numpy.nonzero(
        numpy.max(numpy.abs(coordRMED - cfsXYZ), axis=1) < TOLERANCE)
```

Comment: brilliant! down from `30s` to `0.6s` (real).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to sort both arrays (adding an index column so that the sorted arrays still contains the original indices). Then, to match, step through the arrays in lock-step. Since you're expecting a precise 1-1 correspondence, you should always be able to match pairs of rows off.

Answer (score 1):

A first thing to remember is that by default, in NumPy, "the iteration always proceeds in a C-style contiguous fashion (last index varying the fastest)"[1]. You might improve things by reversing the order of iteration (iterate on `coordMED.T`, the transpose of `coordMED`...)

Nevertheless, I'm still surprised by you need for a loop: you claim that 'The coordinates do not match within python's regular floating point precision': have you tried to adjust the `rtol` and `atol` parameters of `np.allclose`, as described in its [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html)?

[[1]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.beyond-basics.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes, I played with the `rtol` and `atol` values. E.g. `coordsRMED[-2,0] = 0.029583333333331876..` `coordsCFS[-2,0] = 0.02958333333333333..` For `atol=1e-14,rtol=1e-14` `allclose` returns `True`, for `atol=1e-15,rtol=1e-14` it's `False`. The defaults of `allclose` seem to be just fine for me...

Comment: And what's the precision of the floats stored in your h5py? Are `0.029583333333331876` and `0.02958333333333333` *really* different?

Comment: H5T_IEEE_F64LE (64bit) for both. `dtype` is also `'float64'`. These files are from different programs though. Internally they might use a different precision, I do not know. Maybe it's easier to convert them to 32bit before the comparison?

Comment: Up to you: it's your data, you know whether a `1e-14` difference is significant or not. If you suspect that some programs use a simple precision, then yes, converting to `float32` might help.